# What is the use of query parameters in webpack loaders

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am very new to `webpack`.I am trying to understand what is the use of query params in Loaders.Can any one help me with an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`query` params are used to supply addition conditions or information to the `loader`

Example:

```
url-loader?limit=100000
```

This means, `url-loader` has a limit of `100000` characters.

Hope it helps!